# Connect mobile application to existing SQL database

Tags: sql, database, api, mobile

We have an existing SQL database which stores information which is continiously updated through a number of ways.

Now we want to launch a mobile application which uses some of the data stored in the database. However, we do not know how we can connect to this database.

Is this done via API, do some standard solutions exist?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You app, sitting on a mobile platform (lets say a phone) would need to access the database. This will have to be over the internet, and means exposing you database to direct querying over the internet. This is not a good thing: once the database is open, then almost anyone can get to it.

The way I'd do it is put a web-based front end behind which your database can hide. You app sends an HTTP request to your web site. You can include whatever security you can dream up to authenticate that it's your app and not some random vandal. When the web site thinks it's OK, it accesses the database and returns whatever data it needs to. It might return the data as HTML, but JSON is probably better.